# Why am I must use findViewById command inside methods?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on activities communication.

This is my main2activity class:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String received = intent.getStringExtra("input");

    textView.setText(received);
}
protected void changeActivity(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}}
```

I am using a `editText` at mainActivity. Write something on `editText` than

```
protected void changeActivity(View view){

    userInput = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);

    intent.putExtra("input",userInput.getText().toString());

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Mainactivity buttoncommand like this press button and send what am i write on editText. But i dont understand something. if i change place `textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);` this code to out of the method. I am use it under the class. like this

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String received = intent.getStringExtra("input");

    textView.setText(received);
}
protected void changeActivity(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}}
```

application doesn't work on emulator i write something on `editText` and click button then app go wrong. I don't understand this. Reality(For real smartphones not emulator) is that true? İf reality doesn't work. why what is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `findViewById()` after `setContentView()`
Because android load `xml` in `setContentView()`

and after that you can use `findViewById()`